Current limiting ballast resistors in between emitter terminal and output voltage terminal of voltage regulator, is this feasible?
I am working on a 12 to 3.3V series voltage regulator and am not sure if adding ballast resistors R1 and R3 will effectively limit the current through my parallel BJTs. Would this be a feasible solution if I choose to continue with parallel BJTs, or would I need to find some other current limiting solution? 

Well, there is Ohm's law, so they will certainly limit the current through the BJTs.  You would have to be sure that you're not violating the SOA of the BJTs to know if it's "enough" current limiting under the conditions during which you are trying to limit current.  You have to explain why and when you want to limit the current for a better answer. Short circuit? Inrush? Overload?

Active current limiting circuitry will be far superior than your passive current limit approach. Your other issue is that opamp won't provide enough current for the 2n3055's. At these current levels (and Vout - Vin), a modern switching supply makes more sense.

Those resistors are to help keep the current evenly divided between the paralleled pass transistors.
To see how they will limit the current you'd have to take the worst case scenario, a shorted output and transistors saturated and find the current through the resistors.
So you have 12 V on the collector, the 2N3055 is specced at something like \${V_{CE}}_{sat} = 1.1~V~@~4~A\$. With the load shorted you would have:
$$
I = \frac{12 V - 1.1 V}{1\Omega} = 10.9 A
$$
You can substitute in other resistance values to see what they would limit the current at.
Still you would be better off adding a current limiting circuit, there are plenty of examples of them for linear regulator circuits. Typically it's a sense resistor and a transistor so that when the voltage across the resistor is above 0.7 V the transistor starts to turn on and draw current away from the base of the pass transistors.
Your best bet though would be to go with a switching regulator, as your input voltage is 8.7 V above your output voltage so a linear regulator wastes \$8.7 V \times I_{out}\$ as heat. At 5 A that's 43.5 W.

+1. I commented before I read this answer.

You may find emitter resistors like R1 and R3 often when the circuit has transistors connected in parallel for higher max. current capability. The resistors are there to reduce the effect of the differences between transistor individuals of the same type. The total output current would be divided too far from 1:1 between transistors Q1 and Q2 if the resistors were removed. As said, the trick is very commonly used. But I am not at all sure if this circuit has been designed by making proper calculations. Making a linear series regulator which dissipates 75% of the input power doesn't look the brightest idea. But it can still work as wanted. We unfortunately do not know exactly what kind of performance is actually wanted.
If one connects 2 or more same type transistors directly in parallel one of them very likely starts to carry more current than the others. In power applications this can be disastrous because the highest current individual gets hotter than the others and it accelerates the growth of the imbalance.
As you suspected, R1 and R3 dissipate some power and limit the maximum output current, but proper circuit design calculations can manage the unwanted effects. Designing circuits by guessing only, of course, makes the result unpredictable. But even it can be successful if one has developed some instincts of the behaviour of the parts in whole circuits (= he understands circuits, not only separate parts) and checks the quantitative side of the function by simulating before connecting the power on.

The LM358 op amp won't provide anywhere near the current that the 2N3055 transistors will require for high current output.  What is the maximum output current you want?  If you want high current, then you need a buffer transistor at the op amp output.  If not, then you only need one 2N3055.

True. The circuit can be designed by guessing or by making wrong calculations. Or the wanted current output is so low that double 2N3055 stay cool enough without a  heatsink. As said, we do not know what kind of performance is wanted.
